# Sculpting problem in edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, sculpting, object-mode

I can't see my sculpt in edit mode but it gets displayed in object mode and sculpt mode.[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't give us any information on how you sculpted the mesh and what kind of modifier you use - so I will ask my crystal ball ;) You have a _Multires_ modifier on the object to create enough geometry to sculpt. But it is a modifier, the resolution is procedural and the sculpt only built upon this virtual mesh as long as you don't apply the modifier. The _Edit Mode_ always shows the existing geometry, which is still a lower resolution and not sculpted.

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: You could also use _Shape_ > _Apply Base_ in the modifier so that the base mesh will be deformed according to the sculpt - but when the base mesh has a lower resolution this will not be the same as the sculpt. If you really need to see the sculpt in _Edit Mode_ for whatever reason, you have to apply the modifier. But then the change is permanent and you cannot simply go back to a lower resolution.

Comment: A common workflow is to use the [remesh operation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/remesh.html) ('Cltr+R') to model the basic shape of the model (use the 'R' key in Blender 3.5 / 'Shift+R' in earlier versions to visually set the *Voxel Size* value). When you're happy with the basic shape, you can do a retopology to create a low-poly mesh version of the model. Then add a *MultiRes* modifier and add finer details like wrinkles, scales, etc. Finally, you can bake a Normal Map from the *MultiRes* sculpt and use it for the low-poly base mesh.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQfFlzHJJ88 (Dino creature) or here (Grant Abbitt's [Old Man](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn3ukorJv4vu9Tkxju13cHYZCR9kIloe2)) (uses DynTopo instead of remesh in the first step). -- If you're looking for sculpting human anatomy have a look here: https://youtu.be/L5i6SM07DHk (there are several free videos in this channel about female and male heads, body, legs, etc) and https://youtu.be/Sbj-SSdaA_Y

Comment: Is it selected?